# Deserialize wcf xml response using datacontractserializer C#

Tags: datacontractserializer, wcf-rest

In our project, we are getting response from wcf service in xml format which we want to deserialize using datacontract serializer.

Below is the xml response.

```
<ArrayOfCustomerData xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PACRM.QCT">
<CustomerData>
<AccountID>String content</AccountID>
<AccountName1>String content</AccountName1>     
</CustomerData>
<CustomerData>
<AccountID>String content</AccountID>
<AccountName1>String content</AccountName1>      
</CustomerData>  
</ArrayOfCustomerData>
```

We have written the following DataContract class to deserialize the xml.

```
[DataContract]
public class ArrayOfCustomerData
{
    [DataMember(Name="CustomerData")]
    public CustomerData[] customerData { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class CustomerData
{
[DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "AccountID")]
    public string new_AccountID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "AccountName1")]
    public string new_accountname1 { get; set; }
 }
```

C# code for deserialization is given below.

```
 DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ArrayOfCustomerData));
        ArrayOfCustomerData data=new ArrayOfCustomerData();
        using (var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
           var text=stream.ReadToEnd();
           MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
           XmlDictionaryWriter xdw = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
            dcs.WriteObject(xdw, data);
        }
```

when i check the data.cusotmerData, it is returning null.
Can anyone please provide solution for this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the class `ArrayOfCustomerData` - that is just adding an unecessary extra element to the expected XML. You can use `CustomerData[]`, as the type passed to the `DataContractSerializer` constructor, as shown below:

```cs
public class StackOverflow_24673714
{
    const string XML = @"<ArrayOfCustomerData xmlns=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PACRM.QCT"">
  <CustomerData>
    <AccountID>String content ID 1</AccountID>
    <AccountName1>String content name 1</AccountName1>     
  </CustomerData>
  <CustomerData>
    <AccountID>String content ID 2</AccountID>
    <AccountName1>String content name 2</AccountName1>      
  </CustomerData>  
</ArrayOfCustomerData>";

    [DataContract(Name = "CustomerData", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PACRM.QCT")]
    public class CustomerData
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "AccountID")]
        public string new_AccountID { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "AccountName1")]
        public string new_accountname1 { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var ws = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, IndentChars = "  ", OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
        var w = XmlWriter.Create(ms, ws);
        var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(CustomerData[]));
        var obj = new CustomerData[] { 
            new CustomerData { new_AccountID = "String content 1", new_accountname1 = "String content 2" },
            new CustomerData { new_AccountID = "String content 3", new_accountname1 = "String content 4" }
        };
        dcs.WriteObject(w, obj);
        w.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));

        ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XML));
        var cds = (CustomerData[])dcs.ReadObject(ms);
        Console.WriteLine(cds.Length);
        foreach (var cd in cds)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" {0} - {1}", cd.new_AccountID, cd.new_accountname1);
        }
    }
}
```